# Issue with VBA MsgBox code with Yes/No option

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with my code what I want it to do is when Yes is clicked the word document that was created in another module will open. I have used the following code to do that;

```
Option Explicit
Sub Review_Report_Open()
Dim Sheet5 As Worksheet
Dim Status As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim fileName As String
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object

Set Sheet5 = Sheets(5)

Sheets(5).Activate

Status = MsgBox("Do you want to View the Report?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Review Report")

fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports" & Sheets("4. Word Doc").Range("H9").Value & "_" & ".docx"

If Status <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Launch a new instance of Word
    Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'launches word application
    WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    Documents.Open fileName

End If
End Sub
```

I am having a very strange issue that the code only works if it is run twice, one it is run once nothing happens but if you run it again without doing anything it does what it is supposed to!

I have no idea why this is happening if anyone could shed some light that would be great.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Which part of the if-statement was executed? BTW, it is always a good idea to use `Option Explicit`. Right now you have some undeclared variables in your code which does not make it easier to get at the issue. If you have declared them somewhere else which means you have variable with global scope  makes things even worse.

Comment: Yes I debuged the code, there were no error messages, the code works, but only on the second consecutive run.

Comment: you should qualify range("H9"), ie indicate to which sheet it belongs. Something like fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports" & sheets("test").Range("H9").Value & "_" & ".docx"

Comment: Could you please answer the question? Which part of the if statement was executed and which kind of variable do we have?  Debugging also means you checked the content of the variables!

Comment: the option for vbYes is what needs to execute when the Yes button is clicked. and I want to open a word document when this happens, Else do nothing. Not sure what you mean by variable? I have done what you suggested and it now asks for "status" to be defined? I am not sure what variable to use in this case?

Comment: Sorry, but WHAT? You do not mean what I mean by variable? You said you debugged then you should check what is in the variable `filename` and also the other variables like `status` etc. To get more knowledge on the topic of variables chcek [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/).

Comment: Ah sorry I am new to this, I have checked those variables and the FileName variable is as expected (The File path I need) and the Status variable is 6. what should I define status as? Should it be a variable?

Comment: Try, please: `Dim Status As VbMsgBoxResult`. Then, use `If Status <> vbYes Then Exit Sub`. And after this line, use yours: `Documents.Open fileName`. Forget about `If ... End If`...

Comment: I have edited the code to reflect the comments, however, I am still having the same issue that it wil only run correctly if I run it twice consecutively without doing anything else?

Comment: Try, please to separate the problem. I think your code works well in terms of MsgBox. I do not know how opening of a docx document in Excel can influence the code. So, please comment the line `fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports" & Sheets("4. Word Doc").Range("H9").Value & "_" & ".docx"` and `Documents.Open fileName`. Then put instead `MsgBox "OK"`. Does the code work as expected? Otherwise, when you say that it works second time you try the code, what `Documents.Open fileName` does? It cannot be open. Theoretically, this cannot work. Excel does not have a `Document` object.

Comment: @Calum Burns: Can you confirm that your code works in terms of MsgBox, like I dared to sustain it should?

Comment: The Ok message box worked, maybe I will have to open an instance of word in order to make it happen.

Comment: Of course, you must do that! I am only wandering how you do not receive an error when try that strange line  (`Documents.Open fileName`)... Did you use in another sub, running before this one, `On Error Resume Next` and you forgot to use `On Error GoTo 0` of end of it? Try, please, creating of a new sub containing only `On Error GoTo 0` and run it. Then, try running again your code posted in your question. If you do not receive any error, this is above my understanding...

Comment: I have edited the Code above to show what I used, it seems to work perfetcly now, thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209665/discussion-between-calum-burns-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well in terms of 'MsgBox' behavior. You need to properly declare your variables and properly use them.

Then, you must look for a Word existing session and open a new one if not any. A working piece of code must look as following:

```
Sub Review_Report_Open()
Dim Sheet5 As Worksheet, boolFound As Boolean
Dim Status As VbMsgBoxResult, fileName As String
Dim WordDoc As Object, WordApp As Object

Set Sheet5 = Sheets(5)

Sheets(5).Activate

Status = MsgBox("Do you want to View the Report?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Review Report")

fileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Reports" & Sheets("4. Word Doc").Range("H9").value & "_" & ".docx"

 If Status <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    'Looking for the Word open session:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        boolFound = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 'mandatory to avoid VBA surprises
    If Not boolFound Then
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'create a new session
        WordApp.Visible = True
    End If
    Documents.Open fileName
    'Do what is to be done...
 End If
End Sub
```

The code is not tested from reasons easy to be understood, I think. It tries to logically correct things not well used in your question code...

Comment: @Calum Burns: I would suggest you to edit your question and use your initial code. Otherwise, somebody else looking for a similar problem solution will be more then confused...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very imprecise. In order to get at the problem you should first introduce precision.

1. *Dim Sheet5 As Worksheet*. `Sheet5` is a default `CodeName`. That is a name Excel gives to a worksheet by default. We don't know if a sheet by that `CodeName` exists in your workbook. Hardly anybody knows, I guess, whether Excel would avoid giving that name to a new sheet if you have allocated that same name to an object variable. "Sheet5" isn't a terribly *descriptive* name. Find a name that can serve you better and that doesn't carry the same kind of ballast.
2. `Set Sheet5 = Sheets(5)`. `Sheet(5)` looks like a `CodeName`. If you do have a worksheet by that name the syntax should be `Set Sheet5 = Worksheets("Sheet(5)")`. I suggest you read up on `CodeName` and tab `Name` properties and avoid using the same system of creating generic names as Excel uses. That is, if you can't think of names that help you understand your own code.
3. `Documents.Open fileName` is a command from the Word application's DLL. You need to create an instance of the Word application in order to successfully open a document in it. Since you say that your code works every other time there does seem to be such an object floating around in the background. You need to declare it within the scope of your code so as to gain control over it.
4. Opening a Word document doesn't necessarily mean that Excel will close down. In fact, it isn't clear whether the code you offer runs in Excel or in Word. By its name, it appears to be an event procedure. Since you impart no knowledge on that point we can only guess. Please clarify your question in this regard.
5. Excel does have one active Window and so does Word. When a new document is opened that document is given the active Window by that application. So you open a Word document, the Word application's active window will be occupied by the new document. But your code doesn't say what should happen to Excel's active window that was **the** active window until that moment. It's entirely possible that your code does everything right - only it doesn't manage the active Window and therefore the newly opened Word document politely stays in the background. You can check for that once you have a variable object for the Word application that you can query about the names of open documents and the status of its windows.